# What does "Bourlesq" mean?

Tags: classical-music

I found an anonymous piano piece entitled "Bourlesq in G Major".

http://www.sheetmusic2print.com/Notebook-Wolfgang-Mozart/Bourlesq.aspx

What is a Bourlesq? What English term would be an equivalent?

Comment: This is why there are dictionaries.  Plus you might notice the spelling in your image doesn't match the spelling in your text& title.

Comment: This word does not appear in any dictionary... I updated the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Bourlesq' is just another spelling of 'burlesque'.

From Wikipedia:

> A burlesque is a literary, dramatic or musical work intended to cause laughter by caricaturing the manner or spirit of serious works, or by ludicrous treatment of their subjects. The word derives from the Italian burlesco, which, in turn, is derived from the Italian burla – a joke, ridicule or mockery